# Eclipse cursor changes to crosshair

Tags: java, eclipse, editor, mouse-cursor

I was working in Eclipse Java EE IDE. While using it, mouse cursor changes to cross-hair. Now its displaying as cross-hair in editors. Where to change it?

Answer (score 243, accepted):

Most likely this is the block edit mode. Try pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.

Comment: Thank you! It works also in IBM Rational Application Developer IDE (mine is v8.5.5.1) wich is Eclipse based.

Answer (score 12):

Just so to provide solution for MAC again-

<kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>

Thanks to @vsm

Answer (score 1):

Clicking the `0` button while on `num lock` can also cause it to change...

Just wrote this incase any one else was not finding a solution! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Due to certain typo slips these anoying crusor change might turn up.You save your work on diffrent txt file and then close down the work without saving it on the ide .Build up a new class file paste the already written code from the txt file and continue.Enjoy;