# change cursor from block or rectangle to line?

Tags: eclipse, text-editor

My cursor is a blinking black rectangle. I don't know how it became that way. I want to turn it back to a blinking vertical line.

picture -

[image]

Comment: Can you show us some pictures ?

Comment: similar question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10394479/eclipse-cursor-changes-to-crosshair

Answer (score 122, accepted):

You're in replace mode. Press the `Insert` key on your keyboard to switch back to insert mode. Many applications that handle text have this in common.

Comment: you can accept an answer in 8 minutes...bah...than you very much :)

Comment: now I got to know the use of Insert key on a keyboard :)

Comment: Thanks, couldn't find this anywhere else. TIL.

Comment: If its 2021, some Windows 10 laptops accept Fn + insert

Comment: @SamVitare good point! In fact any keyboard that has a fn key can possibly work like this as they tend to default to multimedia keys vs the rarely used default keyboard keys.

Answer (score 20):

If you happen to be using a mac keyboard on linux (ubuntu), `Insert` is actually `fn` **+** `return`. You can also click on the zero of the number pad to switch between the cursor types.

Took me a while to figure that out. :-P

Comment: Thanks for the _zero of the number pad_ thing. I accidentally clicked that!

Comment: a life savior!, thank you a lot! :)

Answer (score 9):

please Press fn +ins key together

Comment: You are correct, just hit the insert key on your keyboard and the flashing will immediately stop.

Comment: press shift+ins