# How to remove this white block in Pycharm?

Tags: pycharm

how can I remove this white block in PyCharm?
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Xp8U.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [change cursor from block or rectangle to line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15728829/change-cursor-from-block-or-rectangle-to-line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The white block is present as cursor and it is the "insert" mode. 
You can remove it just pressing [insert key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insert_key) on the keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Tap to the insert button in the keyboard.