# Cursor changed to crosshair

Tags: eclipse, adt

I am working with ADT Build: v21.1.0-569685
and Eclipse Java Development Tools Version: 3.7.2.v20120120-1414-7z8gFcuFMP7BW5XTz0jLTnz0l9B1

I have managed to click the magic button to change my cursor to cross-hair. I cannot figure out how to change it back

pressing `Alt` + `Shift` + `A` as suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10394490/774972) does not fix my problem

Comment: I just noticed that pressing Alt+Shift+A sometimes makes a notice box pop up in the lower corner hinting at hotkeys for android development (like debug android application alt+shit+A, D) So i think the ADT hotkeys are overriding the eclipse hotkeys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I restarted my computer the cursor went back to normal. If anybody knows how to fix this problem without a restart feel free to answer and i will accept it.