# Eclipse cursor changes to circular crosshair MacOS

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, cursor

Running Eclipse Oxygen.2 on MacOS 10.12.6 (Sierra) in a corporate environment.   Every time I click to expand an item in the package explorer the mouse cursor changes to what I can only describe as a black/white circular pinwheel crosshair : [image: pinwheel crosshair cursor]

(a) What is this cursor called, I re-created the image from a close-up photo and could not find anything like it with a google image search.

(b) Any idea what is causing this annoying behaviour, it badly affects usability.

Edit#1: The cursor stays like this for a prolonged period of time, seemingly seconds or tens of seconds.  It will change back straight away if I move into the text editor area and back again.

Edit#2: Actually it stays that way forever if I keep it still.  Unless I move it across any change-inducing boundary.

Edit#3: I updated to Oxygen.3A and the problem seemed to have gone away.  But actually it had only gone away for subdirectories which I had expanded previously.  For 'new' subdirectories, the problem continues.

Note:  This is a completely different question to '[Eclipse cursor changes to crosshair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10394479/eclipse-cursor-changes-to-crosshair)'

Comment: Are you saying it stays as this cursor? This is the 'busy' cursor it should just be shown very briefly until the expand/open operation completes.

Comment: @greg-449 yes, edited with clarification.  Why did they choose this bizarre thing and not the standard, an hourglass?

Comment: I can't reproduce this, with Oxygen.3a and macOS 10.13.4 the wait cursor is just displayed for less than a second. I can't see anything in Eclipse [Bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/) either.

Comment: This might be caused by [Eclipse bug 506009](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=506009) which has already been fixed in Oxygen.3 or by a third-party plug-in. Does upgrading (_Help > Check for Updates_) fix your problem?

Comment: Updated to Oxygen.3A just now, seemed improved, but not completely - see edits...

Comment: Which third-party plug-ins do you have installed? Are there many files inside these 'new' subdirectories? Are these files modified from outside of Eclipse (modified not by Eclipse itself)?